# Generate code at build (compile) time

Tags: c++

This may be silly question, but just of curiosity, I wanted to know if something like it is possible.

Lets say I have function

```
void Foo(int a)
{
 ...
}
```

And I want to do something like this

```
@pragma mypragma
void Foo(int a)
{
 ...
}
```

and at compile time I want to generate this (if pragma `mypragma` is defined before function)

```
void Foo(void * ptr, int a)
{
    Foo(a);
}

void Foo(int a)
{
 ...
}
```

Or with return value

```
int Foo(void * ptr, int a)
{
    return Foo(a);
}

int Foo(int a)
{
 ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Some example. What I want is similar to [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

Comment: Which compiler? What do you want to archive? You cannot define one #pragma's in VS forexample

Comment: Compiler independent (cross-platform behavior). I need to generate functions for script binding (generated function will be more complex, but for idea I generalized example). #pragma is not mandatory, there can be #define or some other "string"

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the preprocessor?

Comment: @inspector-g I want to use preprocessor. I just need mechanism to tell him, what to do with what and where. I take inspiration in paralelizing, where with pragmas, you parallelize code (I think, that library is OpenMP)

Comment: Considering writing your own C++ compiler to implement this would indeed make it a silly question.  Writing a preprocessor that alters the source code before the compiler sees it is possible.  You are on your own to write one.  This does tend to be a whistle that you'll deeply regret blowing some day.

Comment: @MartinPerry You don't seem to be aware that OpenMP requires compiler support, that is, the compilers implement the ``#pragma``-API specified by OpenMP. It is a lot more than just preprocessor magic which is going on there.

Comment: OP, what are you actually trying to achieve? As others have mentioned, you could achieve what you ask for in your simple example with the regular preprocessor (eg, lots of ugly macros). But right now your request is really bizarre IMHO, and maybe if you tell us more about what you are doing, we might be able to suggest a cleaner solution. Also, if it is at all possible to choose your language of implementation, Python has function decorators which would probably achieve whatever you are trying to do very easily and cleanly.

Comment: For inspiration (or warning), you could look at how Qt does it with its meta object compiler `moc`, which looks for some `#define` macros in source code and generates extra code based on those.

Comment: What's wrong with `Foo(int a, void* ptr = nullptr)` ? Except for void pointers of course.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I am trying to automaticly bind only certain functions to my scripting language (LUA like). I used "similar" (only from sense of code writing and functionality, not programaticly) approach in C# with square brackets like  [Export("script_fn_name")]

Comment: @hyde: don't forget to mention `moc`'s tendency to die with a generic "syntax error" if it ever gets Boost in its sight (e.g. `boost.date_time`). That's the kind of mess OP is getting into.

Comment: If you want to do something like OpenMP, your best chance is to modify the preprocessor of existing compilers. Unfortunately there is no standard way for extending preprocessor commands.

Comment: And what about to use somehow templates for it, to achieve similar behavior ?

Comment: @DanielKO ...hence the "(or warning)" part, though that has never bothered me (using boost on cross platform stuff is too much of a hassle to be worth it, IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this will work for you. You'll need individual macros for returning a value vs. not, and for each possible number of parameters.

```
// pt<x>: Parameter type <x>
// pn<x>: Parameter name <x>

#define METHOD_PAIR1(name, pt1, pn1) \
void name(pt1 pn1); \
void name(void* ptr, pt1 pn1) { name(pn1); } \
void name(pt1 pn1)

#define METHOD_PAIR2(name, pt1, pn1, pt2, pn2) \
void name(pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2); \
void name(void* ptr, pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2) { name(pn1, pn2); } \
void name(pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2)

#define FUNCTION_PAIR1(ret, name, pt1, pn1) \
ret name(pt1 pn1); \
ret name(void* ptr, pt1 pn1) { return name(pn1); } \
ret name(pt1 pn1)

#define FUNCTION_PAIR2(ret, name, pt1, pn1, pt2, pn2) \
ret name(pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2); \
ret name(void* ptr, pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2) { return name(pn1, pn2); } \
ret name(pt1 pn1, pt2 pn2)

METHOD_PAIR1(Foo, int, a)
{
    // Insert body of void Foo(int a) here.
}

FUNCTION_PAIR1(int, Foo2, int, a)
{
    // Insert body of int Foo2(int a) here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use the C preprocessor for this as David suggests, but when you have more complex tasks at hand, you should think about other tools to generate the code you need.

Examples of such preprocessors I have seen in use include `m4` and `python`.

`python` seems to be more suited to the syntax you are envisioning, however, you cannot execute it as a preprocessor, you have to run a python program *on* your file to generate the desired output.

`m4`, on the other hand is a real preprocessor, meaning that you basically feed your source file directly into `m4`, just like your compiler feeds C files through the C preprocessor. Its syntax is very functional in style, which may be good or bad depending on what you want to achieve.